# Different coordinate systems for different objects?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems

As the title indicates, I was wondering if we can use different coordinate systems for different objects. Specifically in the classic inclined pulley problem:[image]

For $m_1$ I usually choose my $x$-axis to be running parallel to the inclined plane and my $y$-axis perpendicular to the plane. However, then I'm not sure what coordinate system to use for $m_2$. I have seen books where they choose their $x$-axis as the actual rope, and the $y$-axis running perpendicular to that rope.

I was wondering if I could set up, in this case, two different coordinate systems for $m_1$ and $m_2$. Here's what I mean by that: for $m_1$ the $x$-axis would be parallel to the inclined plane and the y-axis perpendicular to it; for $m_2$, the $y$-axis would be running straight down, parallel to the rope and the $x$-axis would be then running parallel the ground. Can this work?

Also, do you have any tips on choosing a coordinate system?

Comment: It's preferable to use two coordinate systems, and then use some equation of constraint to link the two.    There are other ways to solve a simple problem like this one such as taking the two masses and the rope as one object, but more complicated ones may not yield to such simplification.    Having a local coordinate system for each object is a more systematic approach that can be applied to a much larger class of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are free to choose different coordinate systems.

You just must tie them together correctly (the rope tension pulling along the $+x$-axis in $m_1$ equals the rope tension pulling upwards along the $-y$-axis in $m_2$).

Tips for choosing coordinate systems? My tip is to choose it so it minimizes the number of acceleration components. That often simplifies the work a lot (you could have chosen an x-axis tilted 45 degrees from the incline - but that would have caused a parallel and perpendicular acceleration component to be present. So don't).

Comment: *"My tip is to choose it so there are no acceleration components."* Isn't it *safer* to state one tries to *minimise* the *number* of acceleration components? If a system is going to move then no choice of coordinate system is going to make that 'disappear'. But careful choice can 'confine' acceleration to (e.g.) $a_x$ or $a_y$ or $a_z$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *one* acceleration component for each object?

Comment: @Gert. Garyp. You are both very right. I have updated that nerving detail.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if we can use different coordinate systems for
>   different objects.

Yes. The choice of coordinate system is always arbitrary, as no *absolute* frame of reference exists (see [Galilean invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance) for further reading).

So it's perfectly possible to derive the equation of motion (EoM) for $m_1$ in one coordinate system and for $m_2$ in another one.

Generally one chooses the coordinate system for one's own convenience. It would be mathematically more difficult to derive the EoMs with an $x$-axis at say $63$ degrees to the gradient and $y$-axis at $-52$ degrees to the gradient, so we tend to avoid that kind of awkward choices.

> Also, do you have any tips on choosing a coordinate system?

As said, mathematical convenience should guide you. For radially symmetrical problems (involving rotation e.g.) we may choose a convenient polar coordinate system rather than a Cartesian one.